# How to add and use variables in shell dynamically

Tags: linux, shell

For example, I have a file look as follows:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Now, I want to use a Linux shell script to set some variables according to this file. I need the following variables to be set something like:

```
export abc=abc111
export def=def111
export ghi=ghi111
```

As you can see that the variable names are retrieved from list file as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read var; do
    export $var=${var}111
done < vars.txt
```